# Garbled Screen After Adjusting Screen Resolution

Tags: screen, display-resolution

First of all: Sorry for the quality of the screenshots.

I run Ubuntu Desktop 18 on an HP DL380 G8 server.

After installation, the screen resolution is set to 1280 x 1024.
I change it to 1440 x 900, what is prefectly working as long as I don't reboot:
[screen resolution 1440 x 900](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEJjf.jpg)

After rebooting the server, the login screen looks OK:
[login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjsVq.jpg)

But then, it gets garbled:
[garbled screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK2gR.jpg)

Any help to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you @Nmath, but my problem is already solved with the answer of texasWINthem (Jul 17th). However, my native resolution is 3000x2000 at 59Hz. Using these values in the answer of texasWINthem resolved my issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (successfully tested with my resolution):

```
cvt 1920 1200 60
xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1920x1200_60.00
```

Please note that you have to replace your resolution in the cvt command above and replace VGA-1 with your actual output. The latter you find by executing:

```
xrandr -q
```

If that worked, I would create a file .xprofile with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 
1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1920x1200_60.00
```

With that you should get the correct screen resolution whenever you login.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly!